# Digitar hora y guardar

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo estos campos en un formulario tipo time

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el formulario** pero al guardar los datos no se me guarda la hora que puse si no una hora extraña es decir si son las  10:30 am guarda en la base de datos las  11:30am aumenta una hora necesito que se me guarde la hora que se digite en el input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EJEMPLO DE LO QUE GUARDA** 
guarda una hora extraña que no se de donde la saca pero no guarda la hora que digite que deberia ser h inicio 10:30 h fin 2:45
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código para campo de formulario**

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label >Hora Inicio</label>
   <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="time" name="hinicio" class="form-control"  >
    </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label >Hora Fin</label>
  <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="time" name="hfin" class="form-control"  >
   </div>
```

**Código para crear tabla e imprimir campos de base de datos**

```
      <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
<thead>
    <tr class="headings">
        <th title="Codigo de la tarea" class="column-title">Codigo</th>
        <th title="Nombre de la tarea" class="column-title">Tarea</th>
        <th title="Nombre de la actividad" class="column-title">Actividad</th>
        <th title="Quien realiza la actividad" class="columntitle">Realiza</th>
        <th  class="column-title">Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">H Inicio</th>
        <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">H Fin</th>
        <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr"></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php 
     while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $id=$r['id'];
       $codigo=$r['codigo'];
        $title=$r['title'];
         $project_id=$r['project_id'];
          $realiza_id=$r['realiza_id'];
           $status_id=$r['status_id'];
            $hinicio=date('h:i:s', strtotime($r['hinicio']));
             $hfin=date('h:i:s', strtotime($r['hfin']));
              $created_at=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($r['created_at']));
               $description=$r['description'];
                 $category_id=$r['category_id'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tareas where id=$project_id");
    if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name_project=$c['name'];
                       }


    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from realiza where id=$realiza_id");
     if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $name_realiza=$c['name'];
                             }


     $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from status where id=$status_id");
     if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $name_status=$c['name'];
                           }
                    ?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="id<?php echo $id;?>">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codigo;?>" id="codigo<?php echo $id;?>">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $title;?>" id="title<?php echo $id;?>">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hinicio;?>" id="hinicio<?php echo $id;?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hfin;?>" id="hfin<?php echo $id;?>">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $description;?>" id="description<?php echo $id;?>">
<!-- me obtiene los datos -->
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $project_id;?>" id="project_id<?php echo $id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $realiza_id;?>" id="realiza_id<?php echo $id;?>">
       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category_id;?>" id="category_id<?php echo $id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $status_id;?>" id="status_id<?php echo $id;?>">

<tr class="even pointer">
 <td><?php echo $codigo;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $name_project; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $title;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name_realiza;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $name_status;?></td>
       <td><?php echo $created_at;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hinicio;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $hfin;?></td>
           <td ><span class="pull-right">
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar producto' onclick="obtener_datos('<?php echo $id;?>');" data-toggle="modal"
                           data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-udp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Borrar producto' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id; ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> </a></span></td>
 </tr>
```

**Código para insertar datos**

```
  $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
     $title = $_POST["title"];
      $description = $_POST["description"];
       $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
        $project_id = $_POST["project_id"];
         $realiza_id = $_POST["realiza_id"];
          $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
           $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
            $hinicio=date("h:i:s");
             $hfin=date("h:i:s");
              $created_at="NOW()";



    $sql="insert into actividad (codigo,title,description,hinicio,hfin,project_id,realiza_id,user_id,status_id,created_at) 
value (\"$codigo\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$hinicio\",\"$hfin\",\"$project_id\",$user_id,$status_id,$realiza_id,$created_at)";
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que a la hora de guardar no estas almacenando el valor de los input sino la una hora del sistema:

```
 $hinicio=date("h:i:s");
 $hfin=date("h:i:s");
```

En Realidad deberia ser asi:

```
 $hinicio=$_POST["hinicio"];
 $hfin=$_POST["hfin"];;
```

Comment: Si no note eso muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estas cogiendo la hora del servidor no la que introduciste

```
$hinicio=date("h:i:s");
$hfin=date("h:i:s");
```

Usa el campo correspondiente que definiste en la vista

```
$hinicio=$_POST["hinicio"];
$hfin=$_POST["hfin"];
```

Comment: Si no note eso muchas gracias